# C# : Console.Read() does not get the "right" input

Tags: c#

I have the following code:
The actual problem is the "non-quoted" code.
I want to get the player amount (max = 4), but when I ask via `Console.Read()` and I enter any Int from 1 to 4 I get as value: `48 + Console.Read()`.
They only thing how I can get the "real" input is using `Console.ReadLine()`, but this does not give me an `Integer`, no it returns a string, and actually do not know how to convert `String` (**Numbers**) to Integers in C#, because I am new, and because I only found `ToString()` and not ToNumber.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace eve_calc_tool
{
    class Program
    {

        int players;
        int units;
        int active_units;
        int inactive_units;
        int finished_units;
        int lastDiceNumber = 0;
        bool game_state;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int count_game = 0;

            //Console.Title = "Mensch ärger dich nicht";
            //Console.WriteLine("\tNeues Spiel wird");
            //Console.WriteLine("\t...geladen");
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

            //Console.Clear();
            //Console.WriteLine("Neues Spiel wird gestartet, bitte haben sie etwas Geduld");
            //Console.Title = "Spiel " + count_game.ToString();

            //Console.Clear();
            //string prevText = "Anzahl der Spieler: ";

            //Console.WriteLine(prevText);

            string read = Console.ReadLine();

            /*Program game = new Program();
            game.players = read;

            game.setPlayers(game.players);

            if (game.players > 0 && 5 > game.players)
            {
                game.firstRound();
            }*/

            string readagain = read;




            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        /*
        bool setPlayers(int amount)
        {
            players = amount;

            if (players > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        bool createGame()
        {

            inactive_units = units = getPlayers() * 4;
            active_units = 0;
            finished_units = 0;

            game_state = true;

            if (game_state == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        int getPlayers()
        {
            return players;
        }


        private static readonly Random random = new Random();
        private static readonly object syncLock = new object();
        public static int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
        {
            lock (syncLock)
            { // synchronize
                return random.Next(min, max);
            }
        }


        int rollDice()
        {
            lastDiceNumber = RandomNumber(1,6);
            return lastDiceNumber;
        }

        int firstRound()
        {
            int[] results = new int[getPlayers()];

            for (int i = 0; i < getPlayers(); i++)
            {
                results[i] = rollDice();
            }
            Array.Sort(results);

            return results[3];
        }
         */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
int convertedNumber = int.parse(stringToConvert)
```

or

```
int convertedNumber;

int.TryParse(stringToConvert, out covertedNumber)
```

to convert strings to integers.

Answer (score 2):

You should really use `TryParse` instead so that you can catch if the user doesn't input a number.  `int.Parse` will throw an exception if it tries to convert a string that is not numeric.

```
 int convertedNumber = 0;

 if (!int.TryParse(stringToConvert, out convertedNumber))
 {
     // this code will execute if the user did not put
     //     in an actual number.  For example, if the user entered "a".
 }
```

The `TryParse` method returns a boolean value which will tell you whether the conversion was successful.  If it was successful, the converted value will be passed through the `out` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

To convert your string to an integer, use `int.Parse(yourString)`.

The reason you get "48 + Console.ReadKey" is that `Console.ReadKey` returns the *code* of the key that was pressed - in this case, the ANSI value of the number character that was pressed.

Comment: That was what I supposed to be my problem, but I did not know how to fix it ;)